# VB 2010 Setup Project trying to find old Crystal Reports dependency rather than the new one

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

I have upgraded applications that use both SQL Server Express and Crystal Reports from VB 2008 to VB 2010. After an unbelievable amount of effort and time, I succeeded with the upgrade of both the Applications themselves and the Setup Projects for them. SQL Server 2005 Express is now upgraded to SQL Server 2008 Express. Crystal Reports however is a different story. I have uninstalled Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 and installed SAP Crystal Reports version for Visual Studio 2010 13.0.4 on my development computer, which installed the bootstrapper for it. I had to install the 13.0.4 Runtime too, so that I could run the applications in debug. They run just fine in debug, however the Setup Projects get warnings about not being able to find the 2008 CrystalDecisions dependencies, even though the 2008 version has been removed and should not be used. The prerequisite for SAP Crystal Reports version for Visual Studio 2010 13.0.4 is selected but I get these warnings:

Warning 1

Unable to find dependency 'CRYSTALDECISIONS.WINDOWS.FORMS' (Signature='692FBEA5521E1304' Version='10.5.3700.0') of assembly 'SCoPe2006.exe'      C:\Documents and Settings\DCD\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects TEMP\Setup SCoPe 2006\Setup SCoPe 2006\Setup SCoPe 2006.vdproj    Setup SCoPe 2006

Warning 2

Unable to find dependency 'CRYSTALDECISIONS.REPORTSOURCE' (Signature='692FBEA5521E1304' Version='10.5.3700.0') of assembly 'SCoPe2006.exe'   C:\Documents and Settings\DCD\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects TEMP\Setup SCoPe 2006\Setup SCoPe 2006\Setup SCoPe 2006.vdproj         Setup SCoPe 2006

Warning 3

Unable to find dependency 'CRYSTALDECISIONS.SHARED' (Signature='692FBEA5521E1304' Version='10.5.3700.0') of assembly 'SCoPe2006.exe'        C:\Documents and Settings\DCD\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects TEMP\Setup SCoPe 2006\Setup SCoPe 2006\Setup SCoPe 2006.vdproj         Setup SCoPe 2006

Warning 4

Unable to find dependency 'CRYSTALDECISIONS.CRYSTALREPORTS.ENGINE' (Signature='692FBEA5521E1304' Version='10.5.3700.0') of assembly 'SCoPe2006.exe'      C:\Documents and Settings\DCD\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects TEMP\Setup SCoPe 2006\Setup SCoPe 2006\Setup SCoPe 2006.vdproj    Setup SCoPe 2006

I have installed these applications on a different computer and they install the SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4, which they should. When I run the applications, I get an unhandled exception “Could not load file or assembly ‘CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version =10.5.3700.0”, which I think is the old 2008 Crystal Reports and the application should not be using.

I cannot find where the reference to a dependency for the 2008 Crystal Reports would be in either the Application itself or the Setup Project.

Can you tell me what to change to fix this?

Thank you,

Dan